# Spring MVC custom validators

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am validating my spring form for that I wrote my own validator. In that I was unable to show my error codes.

I have a model/pojo class.

```
public class Person{
    private String dob;

    @InHouse
    private Contact contact;

   //getters and setters
}
```

So here "Contact" is another class and it has 3 variables.

```
public class Contact{
  private String mobile1;
  private String mobile2;
  private String mobile3;

  //getters and setters
}
```

All my hibernate connections are fine.

Below is my custom validator.

```
    @Override
public void validate(Object argTarget, Errors argErrors) {
    Person person = (Person) argTarget;
    validate(argTarget.getClass(), argErrors, person);
    List<Field> inHouseAnnotationFields = AnnotationProcessor
            .getAnnotatedFields(argTarget.getClass(), InHouse.class);
    if (Precondition.checkNotEmpty(inHouseAnnotationFields)) {
        for (Field field : inHouseAnnotationFields) {
            System.out.println(field.getName());
            Object obj = getValue(person, field.getName());
            validate(field.getType(), argErrors, obj);
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void validate(Class<?> argClass, Errors argErrors,
        Object argObject) {
    List<Field> calidationFieldsList = AnnotationProcessor
            .getAnnotatedFields(argClass, Validation.class);
    if (Precondition.checkNotEmpty(calidationFieldsList)) {
        for (Field field : calidationFieldsList) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object result;
                result = field.get(argObject);

                Object instance = getValidatorInstance(argClass, field);
                if (Precondition.checkNotNull(instance)
                        && Precondition.checkNotNull(result)) {
                    com.rise.validation.Validation<String, String> validation = (com.rise.validation.Validation<String, String>) instance;
                    boolean valid = validation.validate(result.toString());
                    if (!valid) {
                        argErrors.rejectValue(field.getName(),
                                field.getName() + " Validation Failed");
                    }
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code "InHouse" is my custom annotation. Contact(Person Class) variable has this annotation.

In my input I gave a wrong phone number for **mobile3** field.

I am validating each and every field here.Here I am using Reflections. I will add all my error messages based on my variable("Valid"). So when I use "argErrors.rejectValue(arg1,arg2)" I am getting an exception like.

**org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'mobile3' of bean class [com.rise.common.model.Person]: Bean property 'mobile3' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?**

Here my mobile3 is in my "Contact" class. I don't know why I am getting this exception while adding all my error messages to **argErrors** object.

Can any one help me on this.

**Note:** Here I am using reflection to iterate over the fields. For example First I will iterate over **Person** fields (dob) then I will get the **Contact** object from **Person** then I will iterate over **Contact** fields.

I was stuck here. Please help me on this and also is it the right way to write **Custom Validators**.

Thanq,
Amar.

Comment: Hope this helps http://codetutr.com/2013/05/29/custom-spring-mvc-validation-annotations/

Comment: Hay Thanq. But I have a doubt is it using Spring Validation. How can I integrate with Spring controller...? Also the example class has two variables but In my example I have an extra reference variable. The problem with this reference variables. How can I solve these kind of problems...

Comment: Can you show what `calidationFieldsList` holds?

Comment: Hi, I added my whole validator code. You can see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error says that it can't find the property mobile3 in com.rise.common.model.Person
because it's not in there.it'sin contact so you should change

```
argErrors.rejectValue(field.getName(),
                                field.getName() + " Validation Failed");
```

to

```
argErrors.rejectValue("contact.mobile3 ",
                                field.getName() + " Validation Failed");
```

that is nested path of the field you are rejecting the value of

Comment: Hay Thanq Man. Its work foe me. Hay Now I am not getting this issue but I was unable to display my errors in the jsp page. Can you please help me on this. I tried but I failed. Can you please help me on this...?

Comment: Yes you have to use spring form tag for this
path is the nested path in this case contact.mobile3
<form:errors path="contact.mobile3" />
read here 
 http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html it explains everything in detail